# how to retrieve namespace value from the resoucequota object from data.inventory

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

In the gatekeeper template, trying to fetch the namespace from the resoucequota object (replicated using the sync.yaml).

Currently try to fetch using :

`existingrqs := {e | e := data.inventory.cluster["v1beta1"]["ResourceQuota"].metadata.namespace}`

**sync.yaml** used :

```
apiVersion: config.gatekeeper.sh/v1alpha1
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: config
  namespace: "gatekeeper-system"
spec:
  sync:
    syncOnly:
      - group: ""
        version: "v1beta1"
        kind: "Pod"
      - group: ""
        version: "v1beta1"
        kind: "Namespace"
      - group: ""
        version: "v1beta1"
        kind: "ResourceQuota"
```

Not able to retrieve the namespace from resoucequota cached object.

Answer (score 1):

ResourceQuotas are *namespaced*, so you need to use `data.inventory.namespace` instead of `data.inventory.cluster`. I can't find official documentation on referential constraints, so my best guess is you'll need something like:

```
existingrqs := {e | e := data.inventory.namespace[_]["v1"]["ResourceQuota"][_].metadata.namespace}
```

The format of `data.inventory.namespace` is:

```
data.inventory.namespace[$NAMESPACE][$APIVERSION][$KIND][$NAME]
```

By using `_` instead of providing an explicit string, this should produce an iterator for each Namespace, for objects of API Version "v1", for objects of Kind "ResourceQuota".

I don't have a good setup for testing this, but it should get you closer to what you want.